# When do we mark a question a HW question?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking at the question [Which concentration of BSA is recommended for dynamic light scattering experiments?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/2469/389). I really don't think that it is a HW questions but rather a very confused undergrad who doesn't know how to approach his/her experiment.

When do we make the judgement call that a question is a homework question vs. something else?

Comment: I edited and reopened that specific question, and I agree with you that it's likely not a pure homework question. I'll have to take a bit more time to think about how to handle the bigger issue.